# VBA Error Show Object variable or With block variable not set error

Tags: excel, vba

ThisWorkbook  In the VBA Project , it happen in this line
**UserForm1.Button_101.BackColor = &HFFFF00 'happen VBA Object variable or With block variable not set error**

I can't find this error，Please suggest me how to solve this problem?
if I reopen project,it ok.. but i don't know when it happen?

my Cells(1,1) or Cells(1,2) will( 0->1 or 1->0 )

when cells change value ,it trigger  Workbook_SheetChange,Do i need to declare userform ? Button_101 is  CommandButton ....

**ThisWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If (Cells(1, 1) = 0 And Cells(1, 2) = 0) Then
    UserForm1.Button_101.BackColor = &HFFFF00 'happen VBA Object variable or With block variable not set error

ElseIf (Cells(1, 1) = 1 And Cells(1, 2) = 1) Then
    UserForm1.Button_101.BackColor = &HFF

ElseIf (Cells(1, 1) = 1 And Cells(1, 2) = 0) Then
    UserForm1.Button_101.BackColor = &HFF

ElseIf (Cells(1, 1) = 0 And Cells(1, 2) = 1) Then
    UserForm1.Button_101.BackColor = &H40C0&
End If

End Sub
```

---

### **Module Code**

```
Public sst(37) As Integer
Public ssu(37) As Integer
Public cc As Integer
Public dd As Integer
Public count As Integer


Sub ShowForm() 'this is the marco button
    If (UserForm1.Visible = False) Then
UserForm1.Show
End If

End Sub
```

---

### **UserForm Code**

```
Dim btn As Integer
Private Sub Button_101_Click()
If (Cells(1, 3) = 0 And Cells(31, 1) = 1) Then
    ret = Shell("D:\Line1 SERVER\101.bat", 1)
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
    If (btn = 0) Then
    theURL = "192.168.2.201"
    
    With CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate theURL
        Do While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        With .document
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            .all("loginSub").Click
        End With
    End With
    End If
    
End If
    
End Sub
```

---

Comment: You probably don't have button called `Button_101` in your form. Step through your code to find out.

Comment: You are probably trying to set the color of the button, before the userform is initialized. Can you describe your problem a bit more detailed?

Comment: `UserForm1.Show` you are showing the form in `modal` so obviously `Workbook_SheetChange` will not fire unless you are changing the values from the form. And when `Workbook_SheetChange` fires, there is no `UserForm1` active?

Comment: I have an event of button_101, and my excel cells (1,1) and (1,2) will have numerical changes

Comment: I have a button on excel, this button will be connected to the macro ShowForm(), because I have changed the value of excel through other dde methods

Comment: @MG92 Maybe you right... I created a button on the excel sheet, this button is linked to ShowForm(), the userform1 Layout  will display,When cells(1,1) or cells(1,2) have changed, work_selectChange will be called. This problem does not happen very often, but only once. I don’t know when it will happen. It will be normal when I restart excel.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Rout  ...At the time I saw the state that the interruption point of the program has jumped to UserForm1.Button_101.BackColor = &HFFFF00, and the UserForm is currently displayed

Comment: Ok do this. When that line is highlighted, in immediate window, type this `?Userform1.Name` What happens? If you do not get an error then type this `?UserForm1.Button_101.Name` What happens?